# Am I able to fly a multi-crew vessel on my own?

Tags: star-citizen

In Star Citizen, there are several ships you can 'pre-order' and try out in their Arena Commander module.  Some of them feature multiple crew members.

**If I were to purchase the Redeemer, for example, which has a max. crew of 5, will I be able to fly it relatively efficiently on my own ?**

That is, will the twin turrets be operated by the computer (auto-aiming?), or will I literally just pilot the ship, and be unable to use all it's systems and weapons ? (Or will the turrets maybe just fire where I point the nose of the ship?)

Comment: Are all the ships available in the Arena Commander module?  (Or the race module for that matter.)  You might not even have the option of flying that ship.

Comment: You can find a recent status of all the ships here: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/comm-link/transmission/14244-How-Ideas-Take-Flight-The-Star-Citizen-Ship-Pipeline  'Flight ready' means: available in Arena Commander.  So someone with a turreted ship could provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Multi crew ships in at the moment (4. Nov. 2014)

Star Citizen gets released in modules. At the moment there are two modules available: the Hangar Module and the Dogfight Module (Arena Commander).

Currently the Redeemer is only hangar-ready and not flight-ready. This means you can examine and enter the Redeemer in the Hangar Module but not fly around with it in the Dogfight Module. Additionally multi crew ships are not supported in the Dogfight Module. This feature is planned for 2015.

## Multi crew ships in the Persistent Universe

The Persistent Universe is the MMO part of the game with all modules combined and much more. Release is planned end of 2015 (Alpha) to 2016. In the Persistent Universe you are able to hire NPCs to man battle stations in multi crew ships. This will cost you in-game currency and NPCs will be not as effective as real players.

So in the Persistent Universe you can fly solo around with a multi crew ship but with with limited effectiveness and additions costs.

## Is the Redeemer viable solo?

The problem with the Redeemer are the Hardpoints:

1. 1x Class 3 Hardpoint (missiles)
2. 1x Class 4 Hardpoint (turret)
3. 2x Class 5 Hardpoints (manned point defense turret)

The pilot operates usually Class 1 - 3 Hardpoints. This leave the pilot with the Class 3 Hardpoint (missiles) and most of the firepower is in the hand of NPCs. This is usually not favorable.

Comparing that with the Constellation the pilot operates 4x Class 2 Hardpoints (articulated gun) and 6x Class 3 Hardpoints (missiles) and only 2x Class 5 Hardpoints (manned point defense turret) are in the hands of NPCs. So in a Constellation the pilot operates most of the firepower.

See also:

- [Information about the game including ship systems and hardpoints](https://robertsspaceindustries.com/about-the-game)
- [Ship Specs](https://robertsspaceindustries.com/ship-specs)

**tl;nr: No at the moment. Yes in the Persistent Universe. The Redeemer is not good to fly solo.**